# Angular Material Datepicker : larger font in touch ui mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to make Angular Material Datepicker font more larger in touch UI mode.
With `touchUI` directive, I can get more paddings but the font size is same with the standard mode.

`<mat-datepicker touchUi ></mat-datepicker>`

[image]

How can I make font larger in touch UI mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-breakpoint-observer-so-qrpij1) for plugin styles in `style.css` you can change it. If you try to change in component css it will never effect.

```
.mat-datepicker-content-touch{
 .mat-button, .mat-fab, .mat-icon-button, .mat-mini-fab, .mat-raised-button,th,td {
      font-size:20px
  }
}
```